# Pokemon: dialogue spoken by Ursula. Can you tell me the dialogue spoken by Ursula?

Tags: pokemon

I saw an episode of Pokemon. In this episode, the two Pokemon girls Dawn and Ursula were talking to each other. They both are rival of each other, Ursula taunts Dawn in that episode; they both have taken part in a Pokemon contest. Since I am not a native speaker I could not understand what they actually spoke. The conversation was much like this -:

**Ursula:** *Maye! Maye! But you know it isn't sweet as little Dawn.*

**Dawn:** *Ursula*.

**Ursula:** I have a less than pleasure of seeing your performance yesterday; as usual share dumb luck of yours gone passed. However, I do hope you make it to the final round that way when I beat you, you will make me all that much better.

**_______________________________________**

I don't make sure if these were the actual lines spoken by Ursula.

***Can you tell me what Ursula actually said to Dawn? The link of the episode is given below and the dialogue took place between 4:34 to 4:50 seconds.***
Link: https://youtu.be/k_ruXTg9Jfw?t=4m33s

> The dialogue took place at ***4:34 to 4:50 seconds*** in that video.

Comment: are you asking us to translate it for you or something? if you only want to know what they said, you can turn on subtitles in the video and it gives you the words they say

Comment: Subtitles of that video are wrong. So I am requesting that what Ursula spoke from 4:34 to 4:50 seconds.

Comment: do you mean wrong in translation or wrong as in the subtitles don't match the words

Comment: also, do you mind telling me your native tongue, i'm just wondering how you knew it was wrong

Comment: My native language is Hindi. Actually, the words which were spoken by Ursula were not that much clear, she may have spoken those words fastly and the subtitles don't match what she actually spoke. Though I couldn't understand some of her words, I could evaluate if her spoken words match the subtitles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ursula: My, my, what do you know, if it isn’t sweet little Dawn

Dawn: Ursula

Ursula: I have the less than great pleasure of seeing your performance yesterday

(meaning: I didn’t enjoy your performance very much yesterday)

Ursula: as usual, sheer dumb luck appears to have gotten you pass performance stage, and I hate to burst your bubble but you’re hardly capable of winning this.

(your luck have saved you again, I hate to disturb you from your daydream but you don’t have the skills to win)

Dawn: What did you Say?

Ursula: however, I do hope you make it to the final round, that way when I beat you, you’ll make me look all that much better, agreed?

(but I do hope you make it to the finals, you’ll make me look so much better with your defeat, don’t you agree?)

Dawn: no, I do not!

Ash: Dawn is going to win.

4:34 to 5:04

in the brackets are hopefully what would be easier to understand, if you need anything else, leave a comment, hope this helps